Extract Data from JSON String in Google Bigquery
I am pretty new to Google Big Query the same I have solved in SQL Server but not sure where to start to extract the fields and also unnest the fields where there is an element within the JSON string.
JSON Structure
[
      {
        "SRC_FILE": "{\"externalId\":\"tams22024083002235692\",\"contentId\":1590349958,\"type\":\"TVOD\",\"contentType\":\"VIDEO\",\"contentSubType\":\"MOVIE\",\"contractStartDate\":1725429600000,\"contractEndDate\":1851400740000,\"originalAirDate\":0,\"isParentObject\":\"Y\",\"genres\":[\"\"],\"contentProvider\":\"storyhiveyouth.com\",\"title\":\"Youth Community Stories Focused TV Virtual Workshop 2024 Part 1\",\"shortDescription\":\"(Free, Victoria)\",\"longDescription\":\"(Free, Victoria) Recorded workshops from the 2024 Focused TV Film Program by Reel Youth facilitators.\",\"year\":\"2023\",\"duration\":13560,\"starRating\":0,\"language\":\"ENG\",\"isHD\":\"Y\",\"parentalRating\":\"PG\",\"isEncrypted\":\"N\",\"extensions\":{\"isAdult\":\"N\",\"categories\":[{\"categoryExternalId\":\"tvod22021120817460983\",\"isPrimary\":\"Y\",\"orderId\":0},{\"categoryExternalId\":\"tvod22021120412475706\",\"isPrimary\":\"Y\",\"orderId\":0},{\"categoryExternalId\":\"tvod22022011822474826\",\"isPrimary\":\"Y\",\"orderId\":0}],\"platforms\":[{\"platformName\":\"TVOS\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-reach-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/shls/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.m3u8?device=VMX_CORE_HLS\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"AIRPLAY_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\",\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"MR\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-reach-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/sdash/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.mpd?device=VMX_CORE_DASH_ALL\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"CHROME_FIREFOX_HTML5\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-web-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/sdash/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.mpd?device=VMX_CORE_DASH_ALL\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"ANDROID_WV1\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-reach-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/sdash/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.mpd?device=VMX_CORE_DASH_ALL\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"SAFARI_HTML5\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-web-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/shls/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.m3u8?device=VMX_CORE_HLS\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"AIRPLAY_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\",\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"EDGE_HTML5\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-web-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/sdash/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.mpd?device=VMX_CORE_DASH_ALL\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"IOS\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-reach-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/shls/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.m3u8?device=VMX_CORE_HLS\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"AIRPLAY_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\",\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"ANDROID_WV3\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-reach-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/sdash/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.mpd?device=VMX_CORE_DASH_ALL\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"ANDROID_TV_BYOD\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-reach-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/sdash/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.mpd?device=VMX_CORE_DASH_ALL\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"ANDROID_TV_STB\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-stb-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/sdash/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.mpd?device=VMX_CORE_DASH_ALL\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"},{\"platformName\":\"TVA\",\"videoUrl\":\"https://vod-bcvp-reach-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/sdash/bpk/99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7/index.mpd?device=VMX_CORE_DASH_ALL\",\"trailerUrl\":\"NA\",\"pictureUrl\":\"NA\",\"drmInfo\":\"99668ad8-1fc3-4877-84ee-3acb512ce1a7\",\"videoType\":\"HD\",\"packageIds\":[77617,128296],\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"CHROMECAST_RESTRICTIONS\\\":\\\"NONE\\\"}\"}],\"transactionRateCards\":[]},\"defaultLanguage\":\"ENG\",\"extendedMetadata\":\"{\\\"fwdBlocked\\\":false,\\\"rwdBlocked\\\":false,\\\"hasCC\\\":true,\\\"hasDV\\\":false,\\\"isHD\\\":true,\\\"isHDR\\\":false,\\\"isUHD\\\":false,\\\"regions\\\":[{\\\"regionId\\\":7,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":88,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":19,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":22,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":25,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":28,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":31,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":34,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":37,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":40,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":43,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":46,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":49,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":52,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":55,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":58,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":61,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":64,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":67,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":70,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":73,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":76,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":79,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":82,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":85,\\\"isDefault\\\":false}],\\\"dlum\\\":{\\\"defaultLanguage\\\":\\\"en\\\",\\\"languageCode\\\":\\\"eng\\\",\\\"isAdult\\\":false,\\\"originalAudioLanguage\\\":\\\"en\\\",\\\"people\\\":[],\\\"actors\\\":[],\\\"directors\\\":[],\\\"rating\\\":\\\"PG\\\",\\\"ratingMovie\\\":\\\"PG\\\",\\\"umId\\\":\\\"1f6f4d8a-7f35-4f6f-b2b5-4fd278a4bbab\\\",\\\"uaId\\\":\\\"e597b130-5d63-4071-a5de-b5e80f57fcb4\\\",\\\"contentType\\\":\\\"Feature Film\\\",\\\"image23\\\":\\\"https://tl-images-stb-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/v1/static/prod/vod/c8c62c58-73e9-4ff9-90c1-ec1149eaad8f.jpg\\\",\\\"image169\\\":\\\"https://tl-images-stb-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/v1/static/prod/vod/1712bcd9-5848-4dc8-9c42-b15446056018.jpg\\\",\\\"iconicImage23\\\":\\\"https://tl-images-stb-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/v1/static/prod/vod/c8c62c58-73e9-4ff9-90c1-ec1149eaad8f.jpg\\\",\\\"iconicImage169\\\":\\\"https://tl-images-stb-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/v1/static/prod/vod/1712bcd9-5848-4dc8-9c42-b15446056018.jpg\\\"}}\",\"properties\":[{\"propertyName\":\"BTV\"},{\"propertyName\":\"OPTIK\"},{\"propertyName\":\"PIK\"},{\"propertyName\":\"SPLUS\"}]}",
        "extendedMetadata": "\"{\\\"fwdBlocked\\\":false,\\\"rwdBlocked\\\":false,\\\"hasCC\\\":true,\\\"hasDV\\\":false,\\\"isHD\\\":true,\\\"isHDR\\\":false,\\\"isUHD\\\":false,\\\"regions\\\":[{\\\"regionId\\\":7,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":88,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":19,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":22,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":25,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":28,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":31,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":34,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":37,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":40,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":43,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":46,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":49,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":52,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":55,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":58,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":61,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":64,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":67,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":70,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":73,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":76,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":79,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":82,\\\"isDefault\\\":false},{\\\"regionId\\\":85,\\\"isDefault\\\":false}],\\\"dlum\\\":{\\\"defaultLanguage\\\":\\\"en\\\",\\\"languageCode\\\":\\\"eng\\\",\\\"isAdult\\\":false,\\\"originalAudioLanguage\\\":\\\"en\\\",\\\"people\\\":[],\\\"actors\\\":[],\\\"directors\\\":[],\\\"rating\\\":\\\"PG\\\",\\\"ratingMovie\\\":\\\"PG\\\",\\\"umId\\\":\\\"1f6f4d8a-7f35-4f6f-b2b5-4fd278a4bbab\\\",\\\"uaId\\\":\\\"e597b130-5d63-4071-a5de-b5e80f57fcb4\\\",\\\"contentType\\\":\\\"Feature Film\\\",\\\"image23\\\":\\\"https://tl-images-stb-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/v1/static/prod/vod/c8c62c58-73e9-4ff9-90c1-ec1149eaad8f.jpg\\\",\\\"image169\\\":\\\"https://tl-images-stb-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/v1/static/prod/vod/1712bcd9-5848-4dc8-9c42-b15446056018.jpg\\\",\\\"iconicImage23\\\":\\\"https://tl-images-stb-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/v1/static/prod/vod/c8c62c58-73e9-4ff9-90c1-ec1149eaad8f.jpg\\\",\\\"iconicImage169\\\":\\\"https://tl-images-stb-opus.cdn.avp.telus.net/v1/static/prod/vod/1712bcd9-5848-4dc8-9c42-b15446056018.jpg\\\"}}\""
      }
    ]

    Table Name: `jsonsenthil.json.tvjson1`
    Field name  Type
    tblId       INTEGER 
    source_file     STRING

I tried a few things which are not working out
WITH json_data AS (
  SELECT
    source_file,
    JSON_EXTRACT(source_file, '$.SRC_FILE.externalId') AS externalId,
    JSON_EXTRACT(source_file, '$.SRC_FILE.contentId') AS contentId,
    # ... other fields with JSON_EXTRACT for nested paths
  FROM

jsonsenthil.json.my_technical_catalogue_extended_content_attributes
)
SELECT * FROM json_data;
Output copied as picture please excuse me for that

Data is in this Google Sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/107uN0MsCjycEjPxDk5Gg5gEby5X92Ccilq2Hj2S5w0c/edit?gid=0#gid=0

Can you try this: JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(Jsoncol, '$.SRC_FILE'), '$.externalId') AS externalId?

@Dogbert, it appears to be null. I might have overlooked a small detail.
WITH json_data AS (SELECT Jsoncol, JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(Jsoncol, '$.SRC_FILE'), '$.externalId') externalId_1FROM jsonsenthil.json.tvjson1) SELECT * FROM json_data;

You have supplied a link to a Google Sheet but not given public read access so we can't test/see the data.

@Kolban please check now!

Hi Senthil P Nathan, Can you try using JSON_QUERY instead of JSON_EXTRACT?

It works perfectly in SQL Server, but I couldn't crack it in on Bigquery. Any help would be of great use to me.

@NithishKumarRamisetty unfortunately not working maybe I am missing something
SELECT     REPLACE(ca.source_file, "\\","") source_file,     JSON_QUERY(ca.source_file, '$.SRC_FILE.externalId[0]') AS externalId   FROM     jsonsenthil.json.my_technical_catalogue_extended_content_attributes ca

Looking at your sheet, I'm not convinced that what you have is JSON that you expect.  For example, you seem to have a JSON array of objects.  Each object contains a field called "SRC_FILE".  The value of the field "SRC_FILE" appears to be a string.  Is this what you are expecting?  If so, then you will likely have to parse the string value of SRC_FILE as JSON and THEN work with the parsed content.
